# Most efficient way to index into a numpy array from a scipy CSR matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, nearest-neighbor

I have a numpy ndarray `X` with shape `(4000, 3)`, where each sample in `X` is a 3D coordinate (x,y,z).

I have a scipy csr matrix `nn_rad_csr` of shape `(4000, 4000)`, which is the nearest neighbors graph generated from `sklearn.neighbors.radius_neighbors_graph(X, 0.01, include_self=True)`.

`nn_rad_csr.toarray()[i]` is a shape (4000,) sparse vector with binary weights (0 or 1) associated with the edges in the nearest neighbors graph from node `X[i]`.

For instance, if `nn_rad_csr.toarray()[i][j] == 1` then `X[j]` is within the nearest neighbor radius of `X[i]`, whereas a value of `0` means it is not a neighbor.

What I'd like to do is have a function `radius_graph_conv(X, rad)` which returns an array `Y` which is `X`, averaged by its neighbors' values. I'm not sure how to exploit the sparsity of a CSR matrix to efficiently perform `radius_graph_conv`. I have two naive implementations of graph conv below.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import radius_neighbors_graph, KDTree

def radius_graph_conv(X, rad):
    nn_rad_csr = radius_neighbors_graph(X, rad, include_self=True)
    csr_indices = nn_rad_csr.indices
    csr_indptr  = nn_rad_csr.indptr
    Y = np.copy(X)
    for i in range(X.shape[0]):
        j, k = csr_indptr[i], csr_indptr[i+1]
        neighbor_idx = csr_indices[j:k]
        rad_neighborhood = X[neighbor_idx] # ndim always 2
        Y[i] = np.mean(rad_neighborhood, axis=0)
    return Y

def radius_graph_conv_matmul(X, rad):
    nn_rad_arr = radius_neighbors_graph(X, rad, include_self=True).toarray()
    # np.sum(nn_rad_arr, axis=-1) is basically a count of neighbors

    return np.matmul(nn_rad_arr / np.sum(nn_rad_arr, axis=-1), X)
```

Is there a better way to do this? With a knn graph, its a very simple function, since the number of neighbors is fixed and you can just index into X, but with a radius or density based nearest neighbors graph, you have to work with a CSR, (or an array of arrays if you are using a kd tree).

Comment: Your approach to getting the nonzero indices for each row is one of the faster ones.  Another option is to convert to `lil` format.  Each element of the `rows` attribute is the same row list.

Comment: Another approach would be index all neighbors at once with `X[csr_indices]`,   Apply `cumsum` to this, and then use `csr_indptr` to calculate the subsums and mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the direct way of exploiting csr format. Your matmul solution probably does similar things under the hood. But we save one lookup (from the `.data` attribute) by also exploiting that it is an adjacency matrix; also, `diff`ing `.indptr` should be more efficient than summing the equivalent amount of ones.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from scipy import sparse
>>> 
# create mock data
>>> A = np.random.random((100, 100)) < 0.1
>>> A = (A | A.T).view(np.uint8)
>>> AS = sparse.csr_matrix(A)
>>> X = np.random.random((100, 3))
>>> 
# dense solution for reference
>>> Xa = A @ X / A.sum(axis=-1, keepdims=True)
# sparse solution
>>> XaS = np.add.reduceat(X[AS.indices], AS.indptr[:-1], axis=0) / np.diff(AS.indptr)[:, None]
>>> 
# check they are the same
>>> np.allclose(Xa, XaS)
True
```

Comment: This is great. Unfortunately, the framework I'm using does not have advanced indexing reduce functions like `np.add.reduceat`, and I have to use supported functions (matmul) for gradient chaining, so I went with the dense solution. Thanks for the tip on diffing indptr!